Laravel: Fetch record from MongoDB where a key of a nested element contains an array and a variable value is present in the array
I am using Laravel Jensseger MongoDB library. This is the latest library, The old library is this.
I have a record like this:
{
    _id:   $oid('jhe8239jdo1002'),
    data: {
        id: $oid('34gh57jfo1002'),
        entity: 'task'
    }
}

I want to find record where entity = 'task' and id matches with variable $v;
Here is my code:
$inappNotificationQuery = InappNotification::where(
    array(
        'data.entity' => self::$entity,
        'data.id'     => new ObjectId($id)
    )
)->get();

This query works perfectly.
But in some cases, the record structure can be like this also:
{
    _id:   $oid('jhe8239jdo1002'),
    data: {
        id: [
                $oid('efgty456ho1002'),
                $oid('xcf3569jdo1002')
            ],
        entity: 'task'
    }
}

This query doesn't work on this:
$inappNotificationQuery = InappNotification::where(
    array(
        'data.entity' => self::$entity,
        'data.id'     => new ObjectId($id)
    )
);

I also tried to do it this way. But this one also doesn't work
$inappNotificationQuery = InappNotification::where(
    array(
        'data.entity' => self::$entity,
        'data.id.*'   => new ObjectId($id)
    )
);

How can I get this to work?

Did you test it like this ::where('data.id', 'all', [new ObjectId($id)])
